# Explain some jQuery code

Tags: jquery

What is below jQuery code performing ?

```
    inputMapVar.each(function(index){              
      $(this).prev().removeClass(MISSING); 
    });
```

Comment: For reference, [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), [`$.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/), [`$.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code is looping through (`.each()`) the elements of `inputMapVar` and getting the element before each one (`.prev()`) and then removing the class from that element (`.removeClass()`) with the class name to remove being the value of the variable `MISSING`.

**Edit** Just for the sake of clarity, `$(this)` gets the current element in the loop in this case.

Answer (score 4):

Looping through the inputMapVar collection, finding the previous element in the DOM, then removing the CSS class stored in the MISSING variable

Answer (score 1):

That code would iterate over all the CSS classes applied to the DOM object represented by `this` and remove the ones called "MISSING".  I believe there's a syntax problem, however- the MISSING should be surrounded by quotes, as I believe `removeClass` takes a string subtype.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.... if "MISSING" were in quotes, it would remove the CSS Class ".missing" from each of the previous elements that match whatever inputMapVar is.

Comment: MISSING may be defined elsewhere in the code, try looking for 'var MISSING'.

Answer (score 0):

For each element in the array `inputMapVar`, run the function with parameter `index`.

The callback function ran on each element will get the element preceding the element within the array, and remove the class.

`MISSING` must (or should) be a variable containing the class name.